# Mac OSX How can I add plist to bundle and modify the plist

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a plist and I copy the plist to my xcode project but it seems like the file is not in bundle:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
nslog (@"dict %@",dict);
```

but the file plist file is not showing. Question, how can I add the file to project in a way to see in the bundle? also any of you knows how can I modify the plist and save the changes?

I'll really appreciated your help

P.S. I'm using Xcode 5.

Comment: Do you want to write the plist file on your bundle??

Comment: Are you asking how to programatically modify the plist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a plist file in your bundle and modify its contents as:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]; //Path of your bundle
NSString *path = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPlist.plist"]; 
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSMutableDictionary *data;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) 
{
    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];  // if file exist at path initialise your dictionary with its data
}
else
{
    // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
    data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}

//To insert the data into the plist
int value = 5;
[data setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value] forKey:@"value"];
[data writeToFile: path atomically:YES];
[data release];

//To retrieve the data from the plist
NSMutableDictionary *savedData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
int savedValue;
savedValue = [[savedData objectForKey:@"value"] intValue];
NSLog(@"%i",savedValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

`infoDictionary` will return Info.plist file.
You should use `pathForResource:ofType:` method of `NSBundle` class.

```
NSString *commonDictionaryPath;
if (commonDictionaryPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"CommonDictionary" ofType:@"plist"])  {
    theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:commonDictionaryPath];
}
```

*How can I add plist to bundle*
Drag your plist to "Copy Bundle Resources" phase of your build target

*modify the plist*
Copy the plist to your app's Documents folder and modify it there.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
     NSString*pListDictPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourPlistName" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"YourDirectory"];
     if()
     {
            NSDictionary *theDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListDictPath ];
     }
```