# Plist for structured data in Cocoa

Tags: ios, dictionary, plist

I am new to ios dev't working on a iPhone app, and have the need to store about 20 records of what is basically config of the type:

Key 1

Field 1: value 1

Field 2: value 2

Field 3: value 3

Key 2

Field 1: value 1

Key 2: value 2

Field 3: value 3

Etc. This is read only data. Can you do this with a plist?  I'm thinking I'd like to read it into a dictionary to be used at runtime. I'd like a structured type of data to enhance readability of the code.

Edit:
Sorry, I should have been more clear in how I asked the question if I wanted the right answer.  What I'm asking is how I can create a plist that enforces the "structured" aspect of the data.  So - the data is a list of records, containing fields (like a database).  Each record has the same number of field with the same names and same types.  I want to be able to add records to the plist and have it enforce this - for readability.  And I want to read it into a dictionary to be used in my code to look up individual records by key, and then retrieve the values for each field, referencing the fields by name.  So each "record" would be a structure or class, with the members of the structure corresponding to the fields of each record in the plist.

So it sounds a lot like a table in an SQL database.  I'm thinking I want to use PLists because they are a more easily viewed and edited component of a project in XCode - it would make it easier to maintain and document.

In any case, please let me know the common best practices way to do this type of thing in IOS/XCode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add your data to your plist, and so you retrieve them later. But make sure you add it to the app bundle in AppDelegate. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615248/mac-osx-how-can-i-add-plist-to-bundle-and-modify-the-plist) shows you how you can add it to the bundle.